# Servlet Certificate Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, x509certificate

I am trying to develop an authentication module using servlets as targets for different methods of authentication.  For a username/password combination it is relatively simple since I can pull the parameters and call request.login(, ), but for a client-certificate-type login I am unsure how to proceed after getting the user's certificate (via calling request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate").

How can I go about passing the certificate back to the authentication logic (which is most likely going to be JAAS configured in Wildfly) so I can authenticate the user through the container?